# Model binder does not map type properly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Here is my view model for an event which I use when adding a new one:

```
public class AddNewEventViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150, MinimumLength = 15)]
    public string Description { get; set; } = null!;        

    [Required]
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Data.Models.Type Type { get; set; } = null!;

    public IEnumerable<TypeViewModel> Types { get; set; } = new List<TypeViewModel>();
}
```

This is the method from my EventService class which adds an event to the database.

```
public async Task AddAnEventAsync(AddNewEventViewModel model, string id)
{
    Event ev = new Event
    {
        Name = model.Name,
        Description = model.Description,
        Start = model.Start,
        End = model.End,
        Type = model.Type,
        TypeId = model.TypeId,
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
        OrganiserId = id
    };

    await dbContext.Events.AddAsync(ev);
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I am using it in the EventController in the following way:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add()
{
    AddNewEventViewModel model = await this.eventService.GenerateNewAddNewEventViewModelAsync(); 

//this goes to the database to find the available types 

//and assigns them to the Types collection of the model

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(AddNewEventViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    await this.eventService.AddAnEventAsync(model, GetUserId());

    return View(nameof(All));
}
```

For some reason though when trying to add a new event ModelState.IsValid is false and in debugging I was able to see that the Type property of the AddNewEventViewModel class is null for some reason, while the id of the type (TypeId property) is the valid one. Can someone help me understand what’s happening?

Here's my view when adding a new event:
[image]

and here's the binding:
[image]
As you can see Type is null.

Comment: What, exactly, is `Data.Models.Type`? (Also, please don't use `= null!` - it's a _dumb thing_ MS put in their example code EFCore for brevity and to suppress warnings that will confuse beginners, but (imo) should never be used in actual code).

Comment: @Dai, thank you for the response! It is basically representing a type of an event. A type has a name and an id. The name can be animals, fun, work, discussion.

Comment: @Dai, sorry, I am still learning and didn't know this wasn't a good practice. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: @Dai, Here's the model for `Type` from the database models if this helps: https://imgur.com/mKhOqLC. `TypeViewModel` has only name and id with the validations.

Comment: Your Type is null , because you don't submit it , in your view you submit the TypeId. And also in your database you have TypeId column not the Type column.  So,  as 
 Dai said you can add `?` like `Data.Models.Type?`  to avoid the ModelState.IsValid is false  . Besides, you can read [Introduction to relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)  to know more.